# Is "Why doesn't Java offer operator overloading?" a special case? Does it need attention?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

I'm referring to [Why doesn't Java offer operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77718/java-operator-overload) It's clearly popular, with a score of 82 and one answer scoring 100+, but there are a lot of answers and almost all of them read more like part of a discussion than an answer.

Ordinarily, for example, I'd have flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10964160/886887) as "not an answer" but it fits right in with the rest of them.

Should the question perhaps be protected? Should some of the answers be removed? Is the discussion valuable enough to be treated as a special case and left alone?

Comment: Well, I fell asleep before I got halfway through the soapbox commentary, so I went ahead and deleted the answer.  It really doesn't add much value.  Is there anything else I can help you with?

Comment: Boy, what a mess.  I deleted all the answers with negative votes, cleaned up the question a bit, and protected it.

Comment: Looks non-constructive to me, I voted to close.

Comment: There's only one answer to this question anyway, buried in [paercebal's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/194889/438992), which is "because Gosling said so".